# Would you help me understand this video?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, accent, listening

I'm improving my listening skills so I listen to this video but there are some really difficult sentences that I can not recognize, Would you give me a hand, please?

https://youtu.be/WjDV91ohIkE?t=1m

**At Time 1:02**

he says: "No problem, I've got your cover here". Is that correct? if yes, What is the meaning of it?

**At 1:30**

"I had this doing a performance on stage ... The girl I think" 
What does he say between the two sentences?

I think this is the American accent, Is that correct?

Comment: (1)  "No problem, I've got you  covered here"  This expression is explained here http://www.kaplaninternational.com/blog/got-you-covered-idiom-meaning/

Comment: (2) I had this  *[i.e. a moustache]* during a performance on-stage in Vienna once and -- uh -- a very intense scene where the girl I think"

Comment: The quest's name is Christoph Walts who is both Austrian and German. That's why it might have been difficult for you to understand him .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first sentence is said by Jimmy Fallon, the interviewer:

> No problem, I've got you covered here. Here, this is for you. No problem.

At which point the show host produces a box and takes out two false moustaches.

The second extract is uttered by the Austrian-born actor Christoph Waltz:

> I had this [he refers to the false moustache] erm... during a performance on stage in Vienna once *um*... A very intense scene where a girl, I think, tried to kill herself—in the scene—and, and, *erm*..*um*.. I was to convince her not to do it...

The actor has an excellent command of the English language, and his accent is clearer than many a native American speaker. His Austrian accent isn't as marked as Arnold Schwarzenegger's, but it is perceptible. The interviewer Jimmy Fallon is an American speaker. I have no idea where from in the States, I can only say for certain it's not a New Jersey or deep southern accent. Possibly he's from the East coast but I'm guessing; a quick search on Wikipedia will tell you exactly where.

Because it is an interview, and presumably the answers are not rehearsed, Cristoph Waltz mumbles a little while he searches for the correct expression or word to say next. This type of hesitation and mumbling is a typical and perfectly normal feature in everyday speech and one that can cause great difficulty for learners.

Answer (score 0):

"No problem, I've got you covered here."

"During a performance on stage in Vienna once, I have a very intense scene."

American is correct.

Comment: A minor detail: - The phrase "I have a very intense scene" is plausible for him as a non-native speaker. However he dispels this idea with the beginning of the sentence where he correctly uses the past tense: "I *had* this during a performance" The version you  give  is not 'correct American' in my  opinion.  The use of present tense would work for a movie where the scene is preserved for ever. However this was a stage production in the past so a native speaker would have said, "I ***had*** a very intense scene.  To my ear  he doesn't use the verb 'to have' in either form at that point.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK:  I didn't hear the beginning of the sentence. I thought he was just going with the present tense throughout, as in "So, anyway, we get to be in this production, right, and I have this intense scene" or something like that. I should have listened more closely. I stand corrected, thank you. I thought he sounded American. Maybe not. Canadian?

Comment: @Ricky Austrian and German.

Comment: @Rathony: You mean, I have to listen to this nonsense again? Sheesh ....

Comment: Nope. You have to watch his movies. They are all great. :)

Comment: @Rathony: You're right, and so is chasly from UK, he does have a bit of an accent. I would have never guessed German, though.

Comment: @Rathony: All of them? I watched the musketeer thing, it was more insulting than usual (to Monsieur Dumas's memory). There are two German movies I like a lot (enough to have watched them more than once), and I began to like Til Schweiger when I realized he's actually a pretty good actor (in "Judas' Kiss", which no one has ever seen, by the way) - who would have thought! Other German productions of the past twenty years kind of annoy me even more than today's Hollywood crap. The French have gone gaga, and the Italians are making movies for teenage girls.

Comment: No way that the guest has an American accent.  I'd describe it as Germanic or Austrian (though the accent is not strong).

Comment: @HotLicks: I already took back my suggestion. I was wrong. I'm very sorry, very much ashamed, and mean, next winter, to be quite reclaimed, as the poet said.